# React would not access nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have set React state to data from an API

`this.setState({loan: response.data})`

response.data is a nested object

```js
{
  application: {
    amount: 20,
    interest: 10,
    guarantor: {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe"
    }
  },
  userId: "123"
}
```

Normally inside the render function i can access

```
<p>{this.state.loan.userId}</p>
<p>{this.state.loan.application.amount}</p>
<p>{this.state.loan.application.guarantor.firstName}</p>
```

Now I can only access the first child of the loan. Except i practically set the state for each individual item in the object. Note `console.log(this.state.loan.application.guarantor)` works fine.

This is the API call

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/loans/${this.state.id}`)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    }).then(response => {
      this.setState({loan: response.data});
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

```
const {loan} = this.state;
```

```js
<div className="col-md-4">
    <h5 className="title">Full Name</h5>
    <p>{loan.fullName}</p>
    <h5 className="title mt-3">Account Number</h5>
    <p>{loan.accountNumber}</p>
    <h5 className="title mt-3">Phone Number</h5>
    <p>Phone Number</p>
</div>
<div className="col-md-4">
    <h5 className="title">Loan Amount</h5>
    <p>
        {(loan.application.amount).toLocaleString("en-NG", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "NGN"
        })}
    </p>
    <h5 className="title mt-3">Interest Rate</h5>
    <p>{loan.interestRate}%</p>
    <h5 className="title mt-3">Duration</h5>
    <p>{loan.duration} Months</p>
</div>
```

The response from API call

```
{
            "application": {
                "guarantor1": {
                    "fullName": "Ayebakuro Ombu",
                    "residentialAddress": "30 Udengs Eradiri Avenue Off Azikoro Village Road",
                    "occupation": "Accountant",
                    "netIncome": "50000",
                    "placeOfWork": "Dreamworld",
                    "employer": "Ayebakuro Ombu",
                    "relationship": "Employer",
                    "bvn": "0101010101",
                    "bank": "GTBank",
                    "accountNumber": "10101010101",
                    "phoneNumber": "010101010101"
                },
                "guarantor2": {
                    "fullName": "Ayebakuro Ombu",
                    "residentialAddress": "B48 Copa Cobana Estate, Wumba, Lokogoma",
                    "occupation": "business man",
                    "netIncome": "500000",
                    "placeOfWork": "Dreamworld",
                    "employer": "SafeScrow Tech",
                    "relationship": "Employer",
                    "bvn": "0101010101",
                    "bank": "GTBank",
                    "accountNumber": "0101010101",
                    "phoneNumber": "0101010101"
                },
                "mode": {
                    "name": "DreamWorld Savings And Loans Ltd",
                    "address": "30 Udengs Eradiri Avenue Off Azikoro Village Road",
                    "netIncome": "50000"
                },
                "bankDetails": {
                    "bank": "Parallex Bank",
                    "accountNumber": "0101010101",
                    "bvn": "0101010101"
                },
                "amount": 200000,
                "number": "25642",
                "date": "2019-03-22T02:37:58.069Z",
                "purpose": "For debt payment"
            },
            "approval": {
                "amount": 0,
                "status": "Pending"
            },
            "issue": {
                "status": false
            },
            "payment": {
                "schedule": [],
                "completed": false
            },
            "_id": "5c944a86abf7ea09c40301e5",
            "accountNumber": "1000000002",
            "fullName": "Ayebakuro Ombu",
            "type": "Business",
            "duration": 5,
            "interestRate": 10,
            "__v": 0
        }
```

The error: LoanPage.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined
    at LoanPage.render (LoanPage.js:61)

Logging this.state.loan.application.amount logs correctly

Comment: You need to add more about your code, like the format of `response.data`, and where did you put the console?

Comment: it is strange that you refer to `console.log(this.state.user.application.guarantor)`. You wrote `this.state.user` instead of `this.state.loan`. Could it be possible that the `this.setState({loan: response.data})` expression is not exactly like that in the code?

Comment: You will have to provide more code for anyone to help you. Please consider sharing your whole component.

Comment: Is loan an array of objects?

Comment: What's otherwise the error that you getting when you access nested objects in load?

Comment: @godof23 No its not an array of objects and I have attached the errors and more code.

Comment: When you say `this.state.loan.application.amount` logs correctly, where exactly did you try to log it? In the `render` method, or the `.then` of fetch? I am guessing it was the later. When your `LoanPage` component gets mounted, the `render` function is triggered automatically. React will not wait for your `fetch` call to complete before executing render.

Comment: Make sure that the *state* has a `loan` key set, since you're initiating it in the contrcutor.

Comment: @elem4th in the `.then` after setting state with the response data

Comment: Okay, that's your problem then. `render` method got called and blew up, way before the `.setState` happened. I will detail the issue and a possible solution in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a component is rendered (like the following code), React calls the `render` method of corresponding component immediately.

```
ReactDom.render(<LoanPage />, element);
```

Event if you were to execute a asynchronous `fetch` in constructor, or `componentWillMount` method, that wouldn't prevent the React system from executing render.

This is how you should approach this problem. In constructor / componentWillMount, you should set `this.state.loading = true`, and then fire the fetch call. In the `.then` part of fetch call, setState to clear the loading flag like this:

```
this.setState({
    loading: false,
    loan: response.data
});
```

The `render` method of LoanPage can now benefit from the knowledge of 'fetch call in progress' like this:

```
render() {
    if(this.state.loading) {
        return (<h3>Loading...</h3>);
    }

    return (
        <div> Loan amount is {this.state.loan.application.amount} </div>
    );
}
```

You can change the first part of render (in if condition) to display a spinner or some equivalent. You should change the second part to render everything that you are rendering now.